# Using an SKTextureAtlas instead of just calling the image by name

Tags: sprite-kit

Why would I want to do one of these options over the other... I guess, I don't understand how they differ beyond what I have to code

-make a texture atlas named "HeroSprites.atlas" in Xcode with the image "Hero.png" and possibly other variations in it.

Example 1:

```
SKSpriteNode* heroSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Hero"];
//pulls in image from the atlas without having created an atlas object first
[self addChild: heroSprite];
```

Example 2:

```
SKTextureAtlas* heroAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"HeroAtlas"];
SKSpriteNode* heroSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[heroAtlas textureNamed:@"Hero"]];
//pulls in image from the atlas after having created an atlas object first
[self addChild:heroSprite];
```

As far as I can tell, both seem to load the atlas into memory so that I can call upon all the images within. The only reason I can think for this is if there were identical image names in separate atlases, but it would be easy enough to avoid that.

Comment: depends on what you have readily available.

Comment: I just edited my question because I think you may have answered something similar, but not what I was asking.

Comment: well, version 1 is the same as 2, where 1 does the texture lookup internally. You need both variants because sometimes you want to use an already available texture object. Ie to make a clone of an existing sprite.

Comment: So if I were to clone a sprite, I could reuse a texture already in memory from version 2, but version one would go out to the disk again?

Comment: no, textures are cached automatically. The point is sometimes you do not know what the image name was that the sprite was created with, so you can still use the sprite's texture to make a clone of it

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you should know about SKTextureAtlas:

- As long as you save the files directly into the atlas folder in your
  resource tree you don't have to add it manually to file directory.
- Drawing is faster since all sprites with same blend mode and textures
  from same atlas are drawn in one go.
- Does not support mipmaps (and this is sadly not documented by Apple).
- Shares the blend mode among all of its textures (this can be work-arounded by having two atlas', one for linear and one for nearest).

Answer (score 1):

A SKTextureAtlas can improve memory usage and rendering performance. For example, if you have a scene with sprites drawn with different textures, Sprite Kit performs one drawing pass for each texture. However, if all of the textures were loaded from the same texture atlas, then Sprite Kit can render the sprites in a single drawing pass—and use less memory to do so. Whenever you have textures that are always used together, you should store them in an atlas.

Comment: So you're saying that creating an SKTextureAtlas object instead of just calling the texture directly from the atlas is going to improve memory performance?

Comment: I don't know what "calling the texture directly from the atlas" means…

Comment: Make a texture atlas named "HeroSprites.atlas" in Xcode with the image "Hero.png".
You can use both this code:

SKSpriteNode* heroSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Hero"];
[self addChild: heroSprite];

And this code:

SKTextureAtlas* heroAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"HeroAtlas"];
SKSpriteNode* heroSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[heroAtlas textureNamed:@"Hero"]];
[self addChild:heroSprite];

And both work. What is the reason for using SKTextureAtlas when the simpler one works?

Comment: There's little advantage of using texture aliases with a single texture; their power comes with combining multiple textures into a single alias. This combined texture can be loaded into VRAM faster than the individual textures and by multiple sprites all using the same alias the drawing image doesn't have to switch textures as often (making it faster).